# date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

In my case, I want to search with date on clicking calendar. For example: If you want to search the posts from 29 Oct then click the date from calendar, the date will show as list. The other date 1 to 30 is all ok and work fine but the date 31 is got that error message.

My Laravel 5.2 code is

```
$this->timestamp=date('Y-m-d',intval($timestamp));
$datetime=date('Y/m/d', $timestamp);
```

> date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given

I tried with strtotime but the error still got.

How can I fix this? I searched on other questions but I don't understand how to fix this. That error occur. But that error show when choose the day 31, not on other days (1 to 30). The other days are ok.

When I change my code like that

```
$this->timestamp=date('Y-m-d',intval($timestamp));
$datetime=date('Y/m/d', intval($timestamp));
```

The error is solved but the date show is not correct. The date always show 1970/01/01.

Comment: What was unclear about "date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given"? That seems fairly explicit to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just format your timestamp with the `format()` function like this:

`$timestamp->format('Y/m/d');`

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: No. It's not... :(

Comment: So you tried
`$datetime = $this->timestamp->format('Y/m/d')` ?

still the same error?

Comment: Could post more code of how you process further with the `$datetime`?